# Can i target specific audience in a data extension for an email?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data, sql

I have a data extension in which i have a list of email address of customers.

In that data different types of customers.

I know one option is to create filter if i want to send email to specific type of customers only.

But creating thousands of data filters is not feasible.

Is it possible to send email and use whole data extension as an audience but only target one or two type? Like sending to DE that contains all customers and specify somehow where type = 1 or 2?

Comment: What you are describing is literally the definition of filters. To not require a mass filter creation in the SFMC UI, you will likely need to schedule out your emails via API - which would require you to determine the audience, email template, etc. in a third party system. BUT this can then lead you into the same exact issue, just on another system.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using exclusion scripts.
Add an exclusion script expression something like this.

```
AttributeValue('type')!=1 AND AttributeValue('type')!=2
```

If the expression returns true for a subscriber that subscriber will be excluded from the send.

For example, for Customer with type=4, this expression returns true and hence the customer will be excluded from the send.

Comment: Is this an AMPscript? Just so I understand this - I will need to add exclusion ampscript in the email body so that when email is sent to a data extension that includes all records, the exclusion ampscript will not send email to customer types that are mentioned as exclusion in the ampscript? With this approach my concern is that since i have almost thousand TYPES, if i want to send email to type 1 to 10,,i will have to manually add 990 types in the exclusion ampscript.

Comment: Yes this is ampscript. This ampscript block has to be included in the Exclusion Script section under the Advanced options when you are sending the email either from content builder or journey builder or user initiated email.  yes you need to update your exclusion everytime.

Comment: Is there any way to send email based on sql query to target specific audience in a data extension?

Comment: You have to store the sql query output data to a data extension and then you can send the emails.